# Filter words in Java

Tags: java, apache, data-structures, netbeans

***SPOILER ALERT --- THIS IS AN ASSIGNMENT QUESTION ***

Hi all, so I am trying to figure out this.

Write a program which takes a Java program as input and outputs the program, numbering the lines, followed by an alphabetical cross-reference listing of all user identifiers; that is, a user identifier is followed by the numbers of all lines in which the identifier appears. If an identifier appears more than once in a given line, the line number must be repeated the number of times it appears. **The cross-reference listing must not contain Java reserved words, words within character strings or words within comments**.

Its the bold part of the question I am getting some issues with

I am still outputting reserved words. Can I get a hint on how to tweak my solution. I know there are other issues in code below but I just like help with the above

**MY SOLUTION**

```
    and                   8
    args                 30, 34
    arguments            30
    arr                  38, 42, 44, 56, 66, 80, 90, 98,126,128,132
    author               20
    binarysearch         44, 56
    boolean             126
    case                 90, 90, 98
    change                4,  6
    choose                4,  6
    class                24
    command              30
    datastructures       12
    did                  88
    editor                8
    else                 90, 98
    end                  66, 72, 76, 94
    false                90,144
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
BinaryTree bst = new BinaryTree();// contains all words
BinaryTree keyWords = new BinaryTree();//contains keywords
BinaryTree finalList = new BinaryTree();
linecount = 0;

while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    out.printf("%d %3d. %s\n", currentLine++, ++currentLine, line);
    getWordsOnLine(line, bst);
    compareTwoTrees(bst.root, keyWords.root);
};     
    out.printf("\nlineCount     \nWords      LineNumber \n\n");
    bst.inOrder(); 
    out.printf("\n\n");
    out.printf("...........................................\n\n");
    keyWords.inOrder();
    out.printf("...........................................\n\n");
    finalList.inOrder();
    out.close();
}

public static void getWordsOnLine(String inputLine, BinaryTree bst) {
    Scanner inLine = new Scanner(inputLine);
    inLine.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
    while (inLine.hasNext()) {
    String word = inLine.next().toLowerCase();
    TreeNode node = bst.findOrInsert(new NodeData(word));
    ListNode p = new ListNode(currentLine);
    p.next = node.data.firstLine;
    node.data.firstLine = p;
 }
}

public static boolean compareTwoTrees(TreeNode one, TreeNode two){
    if(one == two)return true;
    if(one==null || two == null)return false;
    if(one.data != two.data)return false;
return compareTwoTrees(one.left, two.right) && compareTwoTrees(one.right, two.right);
}

}

class NodeData {
    String word;
    ListNode firstLine;

public NodeData(String w) {
    word = w;
    firstLine = null;
}

public int compareTo(NodeData d) {
    return this.word.compareTo(d.word);
}

public void visit() {
    this.printAWord();
}

public void printAWord() {
    CrossReference.out.printf("%-20s", word);
    printLineNumbers(firstLine.next); 
    CrossReference.out.printf("%3d\n", firstLine.lineNum); 

}
```

**PS... any recommendations to a good gui channel for tutorials**

Comment: [1] For detecting reserved words, take a look at the `enum` [javax.lang.model.SourceVersion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html) which has methods such as `isIdentifier​()` and `isKeyword()`. Its behavior obviously differs based on the Java release being used. [2] Your question is off-topic since it is explicitly seeking recommendations, which means it may be closed. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for clarification.

Comment: @skomisa Yes.....It helped